# I want to get 2 points that have the closest distance to the value entered by the user

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, pyspark

Hope you are doing well. Here is one problem needs your help.
I am working with some data on pandas.

[image]

I want to get 2 points that have the closest distance to the value entered by the user.

For example, if I input d=4, I want to get the fastest way to output the result  ((C:18 and F:14) or (B:3 and D:7)). The method I implemented is a method used by elementary school students, so I am ashamed to post it.

pandas or pyspark will be helpful for me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit complicated so I built a class to hold all the methods. Each method should hopefully be self-explanatory Using [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) and [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```
import heapq
from itertools import combinations

import pandas as pd


class ClosestDistances:
    """
        :arg data: pd.DataFrame
        :arg user_selection: int
        :arg points: int
        :return list[tuple(dict, dict)]
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        df = kwargs.get("data")
        self.user_selection = kwargs.get("user_selection")
        self.points = kwargs.get("points")
        self.df_mapping = dict(zip(df["letter"], df["number"]))

    def main(self) -> list:
        possible_combinations = self.possible_combinations()
        closest_points = self.nearest_difference(possible_combinations)

        return self.map_nearest(closest_points)

    def nearest_difference(self, combos: list) -> list:
        return heapq.nsmallest(self.points, combos, lambda x: abs((x[0] - x[1]) - self.user_selection))

    def possible_combinations(self) -> list:
        return [sorted(x, reverse=True) for x in combinations(self.df_mapping.values(), self.points)]

    def get_keys(self) -> dict:
        return {v: k for k, v in self.df_mapping.items()}

    def map_nearest(self, closest_points: list) -> list:
        iterator = iter([{self.get_keys().get(x): x} for i in closest_points for x in i])

        return list(zip(iterator, iterator))


data = pd.DataFrame({
    "letter": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"],
    "number": [12, 3, 18, 7, 11, 14, 5]
})

closest = ClosestDistances(data=data, user_selection=4, points=2).main()
print(closest)

[({'D': 7}, {'B': 3}), ({'C': 18}, {'F': 14})]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked this and it's working correctly.

Comment: You are most welcome! Good to hear!

Answer (score 1):

We could try with `merge`

```
input = 4 
out = df.assign(key = df['Value']-input).merge(df.assign(key=df['Value']),on='key')
Out[59]: 
  Name_x  Value_x  key Name_y  Value_y
0      C       18   14      F       14
1      D        7    3      B        3
2      E       11    7      D        7
```

Comment: Hi, Benny, this way seems to provide the result that has only same value with input. When I input 10, I can not see result. Could you explain to me another way please ?